# __init__ and self in Python 3

Tags: python

Does anyone know what `__init__` and self means in Python - a simple and understandable explanation.
I have a basic understanding and wish to expand.
Where would such code be used for?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## self

The word `self` is used to represent the instance of a class. By using the "self" keyword we access the attributes and methods of the class in python.

## **init** method

`_init__` is a reserved method in python classes. It is called as a constructor in object oriented terminology. This method is called when an object is created from a class and it allows the class to initialize the attributes of the class.
Example

Find out the cost of a rectangular field with breadth(b=120), length(l=160). It costs x (2000) rupees per 1 square unit

```py
class Rectangle:
   def __init__(self, length, breadth, unit_cost=0):
       self.length = length
       self.breadth = breadth
       self.unit_cost = unit_cost
   def get_area(self):
       return self.length * self.breadth
   def calculate_cost(self):
       area = self.get_area()
       return area * self.unit_cost
# breadth = 120 units, length = 160 units, 1 sq unit cost = Rs 2000
r = Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)
print("Area of Rectangle: %s sq units" % (r.get_area()))
```

## Output

This gives the output

```
Area of Rectangle: 19200 sq units
Cost of rectangular field: Rs.38400000
```

Comment: `self` is not a keyword. It's just a conventional parameter name. `__init__` is not reserved so much as a hook with a existing usaage, and is it a constructor, but an initializer. (`__new__` is the constructor.)

Comment: Would you like to correct the statement sir ?